# jQuery append PHP code

Tags: php, jquery, append

What i'm trying to do is something like this:

I have this javascript function that appends some content by calling a PHP function.

```
<script>
function example(variable) {
    $('#div').append("<?php someFunctionPhp('"+variable+"'); ?>");
}
</script>
```

Inside the PHP function, i have something like:

```
function someFunctionPhp($variable){

    switch ($variable) {
    case 'Y' :
        echo 'Year'; break;

    case 'M' :
        echo 'Month'; break;

    case 'D' :
        echo 'Day'; break;
    }

}
```

Assuming that I make a call for `example('M')`, i've tested and the function `someFunctionPhp` does receives `M` as value for the parameter (if I just `echo $variable` inside the function it shows `M`), the problem is: it does not enter in the `case 'M'` situation. It doesn't recognize the `M` passed by the JS variable as equal.

If I change the code line in JS function for:

```
$('#div').append("<?php someFunctionPhp('M'); ?>");
```

It works...

Some hint?

Answer (score 11):

php is executed server-side and *generates* JavaScript code, which is executed client-side. You should simply implement your function in JavaScript:

```
$('#div').append(function(dateSpec) {
    switch (dateSpec) {
    case 'Y' :
        return 'Year';
    case 'M' :
        return 'Month';
    case 'D' :
        return 'Day';
    }
}(variable));
```

Comment: Well, i understand that... the thing is: it does work the way I made it.. the PHP function does receives the parameter M but it doesn't recongnize as equal in the case situation. That is the question

Comment: @Rafael It does work in that `someFunctionPhp` is immediately called with the literal argument `'"+variable+"'`. Since there is case for that (strange) value, it simply does nothing. Apart from XHR requests(and similar calls), there is no way to call php functions from JavaScript.